# PySpark add boolean column and handle nulls

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Say I have a null-containing DF as follows:

```
In [45]: df2.show()
+-----+----+
|name1|   v|
+-----+----+
| john| 1.0|
| null| 4.0|
|  meh|null|
+-----+----+
```

I'd like to add a label (for ML training), such that `label` is True if and only if `name1` is `john`. This is what I'm doing:

```
In [47]: df3 = df2.withColumn('label', (df2.name1=='john'))
In [48]: df3.fillna(False, ['label']).show()
+-----+----+---------+
|name1|   v|    label|
+-----+----+---------+
| john| 1.0|     true|
| null| 4.0|    false|
|  meh|null|    false|
+-----+----+---------+
```

Is there a more idiomatic way of doing this? I found `df2.withColumn('label', (df2.name1=='john') & ~df2.name1.isNull())` works, though I don't understand why it works.

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: @Lamanus Well, with the latter approach using `& ~df2.name1.isNull()`, why doesn't it still include `null`s?

Comment: Since you check nullable. Before that, it doesn't check and skipped.

Comment: @Lamanus Hmm - I tried `df2.withColumn('b', (df2.name1=='john') | ~df2.name1.isNull())`, where I use `|` instead, and this produce `null`s. Why does this "skip" but `&` doesn't?

Comment: hmm... interesting. :)